# Static TableViewController not showing cells on presentation

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, ios13

I'm trying to present a settings screen in my app, implemented as a `UITableViewController` of style `.insetGrouped` with static cells.
The `UITableViewController` is designed in storyboard and I'm presenting it with a storyboard identifier.

The problem is, that the cells do not appear upon presentation, and it looks like they only appear as soon as scrolling or tapping on the table view occurs.
In my `UITableViewController` class I don't have any delegate code, but also if I try adding it nothing changes.
I've tried calling `reloadData()`, `layoutIfNeeded()` and tried messing with the presentation style but none if these seem to relate to the problem.

Another thing I noticed is that calling:

```
tableView.scrollToRow(at: IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0), at: .top, animated: true)
```

Before physical scrolling does "wake" the table view and it shows the cells but looks glitchy until physical scrolling or tap. Additionally, in `viewDidLoad()`, `tableView.visibleCells.count` is 0, so the problem has to do with the cells not being drawn specifically.

Here is a visual example of my problem:

[image]

Comment: Do you have any other code being called? Or, do you simply have a button tap action, which instantiates the settings VC and then executes `present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)`?

Comment: Presentation is the most generic it could be without any additional code, as you said. Tap action, storyboard instantiation, presentation.

Comment: What controller are you using to present it? Nav controller or the view controller

Comment: @Eilon - quick test, and I'm not seeing the same behavior. Try this project and see if you get different results: https://github.com/DonMag/SettingsPresent